# what is returned after pathname expansion in shell?

Tags: shell, pathname

**1、a string separated by white space?**
If I execute `rm -r *.txt` where there is a lot of TXT file,I get an "Argument list too long" error,it seems to tell me that it equasl to `rm -r a.txt b.txt...c.txt` after pathname expansion.
**2、just a list object used by the specific command?**
If I execute `tar --exclude *.txt a.tar.gz a` where there are two TXT files ("a.txt" and "b.txt") ,the result is not the same as executing `tar --exclude a.txt b.txt a.tar.gz a`.According to that,maybe we can get the conclusion that just a list object is returned,not a string separated by white space.

I have a dir named a,the structure is like:

`a
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
└── cc`

If I execute `tar --exclude *.txt -czvf a.tar.gz a`,I get result as:

`a/
a/cc`

"a.tar.gz" is generated successfully without *.txt file. 
If I execute `tar --exclude a.txt b.txt -czvf b.tar.gz a`,I get result as:

`tar: b.txt：cat not stat: no such file or directory
a/
a/cc
a/b.txt`

"b.tar.gz" is generated without a.txt and with cc and b.txt

@Jan Hudec

Comment: `tar --exclude *.txt a.tar.gz a` when there are exactly `a.txt` and `b.txt` in local directory, will expand *exactly to the same command as* `tar --exclude a.txt b.txt a.tar.gz a`. Didn't you use some quotes that you forgot to write?

Comment: I posted an answer for supplement below.Thanks

Comment: That's not an answer, it is an amendment to the question. So please, **edit the question**.

Comment: Sorry for that.Now I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. It returns a *list of strings*.

Word splitting is performed *before* filename generation, so at that point, shell already works with a list of strings that will form the command. The generated filenames are inserted, as a separate entry each, into that list.

> If I execute rm -r *.txt where there is a lot of TXT file,I get an "Argument list too long" error,it seems to tell me that it equasl to rm -r a.txt b.txt...c.txt after pathname expansion.

So, yes, it is. And if some of the files has space in its name, it will be passed correctly (which it wouldn't if the pattern returned a space-separated string). However:

> If I execute `tar --exclude *.txt a.tar.gz a` where there are two TXT files ("a.txt" and "b.txt") ,the result is not the same as executing `tar --exclude a.txt b.txt a.tar.gz a`.

You forgot to mention the files are in the `a` directory. Therefore the `*.txt` will *not* expand to `a.txt`, `b.txt`, because there are no such files—there are only `a/a.txt` and `a/b.txt`. And here comes a *quick* of bash (zsh can be configured either way): a pattern that does not match anything is left as is. So

```
tar --exclude *.txt a.tar.gz a
```

expands to just `tar`, `--exclude`, `*.txt`, `a.tar.gz` and `a`. And `tar` does it's own wildcard processing for the parameter to `--exclude` option.

However, if there were also `c.txt` and `d.txt` in the current directory, it would expand to `tar`, `--exclude`, `c.txt`, `d.txt`, `a.tar.gz` and `a` and break down. To prevent that, quote the pattern:

```
 tar --exclude '*.txt' a.tar.gz a
```

Comment: Yes,perfect answer!    By the way,I think someone will want to know that `*` in shell wildcard pattern can not match `/` and `*` in tar wildcard pattern can match `/`.    Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

A string separated by white space. The expansion is done by the shell before passing arguments to the command. When using tar if you want to pass a pattern to the --exclude option put it between single quotation marks, like `tar --exclude '*.txt' -czf a.tar.gz a`

Comment: No, it is not. Word splitting is performed *before* filename generation.